# Test Post Controller con Rspec en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

llevo poco tiempo investigando con Ruby on Rails y tengo una duda respecto a cómo debería testear correctamente mi Controller utilizando Rspec en.
Empecé la casa por el tejado, dejando el test para el final, y aunque en la comunicación entre el frontend y la api responde correctamente con un status:201 cuando todo va bien, en el test me devuelve un status:200.

este es mi `User_Post_Controller`:

```
  # POST /user
  def create
    begin
      userName = params[:name]
      CreateUserService.saveUser(userName)
      json_response(userName, 201)  
    rescue Errors::UserExist
      e = Errors::UserExist.new
      json_response(e.message, e.status)
    end    
  end
```

El Routes.rb:

```
  post 'user', controller: :user_post, action: :create
```

Y este es el Test que estaba diseñando:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
require './app/controllers/user_post_controller'
RSpec.describe UserPostController, type: :request do
  describe "Create User" do
    it "return status 201 when user is created" do
      post "/user", params: {name: 'user'}
      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    end
  end
end
```

Dejo también por aquí la traza que me devuelve el test por consola:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(201)

   expected: 201
        got: 200

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/user_post_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

¿Cómo es posible que esté devolviendo un {status: 200} ?

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Creo que el problema debe estar en el método json_response

Comment: Tienes razón, ese json_response básicamente formateaba el formato de salida de la petición con un `render :json => {status: 'status', message: 'message'}`, parece que no le gustaba el formato (devolviendo el json sin el `render :json` actúa con normalidad) pero me desconcierta que en lugar de un error, devuelva un 200